# Is it allowed to use 'however' with 'in spite of'?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Can you please tell me if it is permissible to use "however" with "in spite of" at the beginning of a sentence such as this one:

> The proposed model is efficient. However, in spite of positive impacts such as a, b and c, we conclude that the model should not be implemented as described above.

Comment: I've certainly seen worse.  One does need to be wary of overloading a sentence with "however", "in spite of", "nevertheless", "on the other hand", et al, but in the above situation it works.

Comment: There's nothing remotely unusual about sentences like *However, in spite of X, [some statement]*. The word ***however*** contrasts with a *preceding* statement (here, *the model is efficient*), whereas ***in spite of*** contrasts the cited positive impacts with the conclusion.

Comment: I agree that it's fine to say "however, in spite of something, something else.." One thing (however) is that I would not use 'however' at the beginning of a sentence. Use it only after a semi-colon or in a parenthetical (e.g., "This, however, does not mesh with that.")

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentence, "however" means simply "but"; it is there to indicate that what follows will run counter to the direction of the preceding comment. In contrast, "in spite of" means "even though one must acknowledge..."; it is there to indicate that even though the tendency or conclusion of the present sentence will go against the previous sentence, further argument or evidence on behalf of the previous sentence's direction can be put forward.

Evidently "however" and "in spite of" represent two different reversals of direction—and setting them next to each other is certainly a valid thing to do under the right circumstances. The main drawback of using multiple signals of redirection in a small amount of space is that the reader can become confused about what is contradicting or countering what. In the example sentence, however, I don't see any problems with the coherence of the statement.

---

That brings us to a second issue (mentioned in passing by CactusHouse in a comment above): whether it is inappropriate to begin a sentence with the word "however." I worked for an editor in chief who felt very strongly tht beginning sentences with "however" was wrong, but I never obtained a clear explanation from him about the nature of the offense. Here is what Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage* (2003) has to say on the subject:

> **however. A. Beginning Sentences with.** It seems everyone has heard that sentences should not begin with this word—not, that is, when a contrast is intended. But doing so isn't a grammatical error; it's merely a stylistic lapse, the word *But* ordinarily being much preferable. [Cross-reference omitted.] The reason is that *However*—three syllables followed by a comma—is a ponderous way of introducing a contrast,and it leads to unemphatic sentences. [Examples omitted.]
>
> But when used in the sense "in whatever way" or "to whatever extent," however,(not followed by a comma) is unimpeachable at the beginning of a sentence. [Example omitted.]

I still don't understand the blanket criticism here. No doubt *however* has three syllables and *but* has only one, but it seems to me that there are many occasions when emphasizing the shift in direction or tendency calls for the three-syllable word, if only to give the reader time to recognize the shift and perhaps get a sense of its seriousness. The notion that *however* as a transition word is inherently "ponderous" doesn't strike me as at all obvious. Moreover, I don't see how it becomes less ponderous when shifted to the middle of a sentence, as, for example, here:

> The proposed model is efficient. In spite of positive impacts such as a, b and c, however, we conclude that the model should not be implemented as described above.

The word remains three syllables long, and it continues to signal a transition, so why is it so much better when it appears midway through a sentence (with commas on both sides of it) instead of at the beginning (with only a following comma)? As Garner concedes, the issue here isn't grammatical; it's stylistic. But whether *However* at the beginning of a sentence constitutes a stylistic lapse, or whether hostility to it is an artificial and learned behavior, as hostility to split infinitives still is in some quarters, is a question I haven't been able to resolve.

In spoken English, people commonly use "however" at the beginning of sentences, and no one is the worse for it. In written English, even with the higher standard of coherence and conciseness that it demands, I see nothing wrong with beginning sentences with *However*. But some people do, so proceed at your own risk.